# generate android pie_chart with database

Tags: android, sqlite, pie-chart

can anyone suggest me the best tutorials or sample code for generate pie-chart with the database values.Already i have visited the  MPAndroidChart documentations but still it is confusing.Thank you!

Comment: see this... http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/learn-to-create-a-pie-chart-in-android-with-mpandroidchart/

Answer (score 3):

I used MPAndroid's Pie chart to display Attendance

```
Add the following to your project level build.gradle:

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

    Add this to your app build.gradle:

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
}
```

> Below in Java Code

```
pieChartAttendance.setPressed(false);

        pieChartAttendance.setUsePercentValues(true);
        pieChartAttendance.setRotationEnabled(false);
        pieChartAttendance.setHoleRadius(0);
        pieChartAttendance.setDescription("");
        pieChartAttendance.animateXY(1000, 1000);
        pieChartAttendance.setDrawHoleEnabled(false);
        pieChartAttendance.invalidate();
        Legend pieLegend = pieChartAttendance.getLegend();
        pieLegend.setEnabled(false);
        ArrayList<Entry> arrayList = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayListXAxis = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Percentage of Attendance
        float presentPercentage = (presentCount * 100) / totalAttendance;
        float absentPercentage = (absentCount * 100) / totalAttendance;


        arrayList.add(new Entry(presentPercentage, 0));
        arrayList.add(new Entry(absentPercentage, 1));

        arrayListXAxis.add("Present");
        arrayListXAxis.add("Absent");
        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(arrayList, "");
        dataSet.setSliceSpace(2);
        dataSet.setSelectionShift(2);

        //Color Array
        ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        colors.add(Color.rgb(76, 175, 80));
        colors.add(Color.rgb(244, 67, 54));
        dataSet.setColors(colors);

        PieData piedata = new PieData(arrayListXAxis, dataSet);
        piedata.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
        piedata.setValueTextSize(11f);
        piedata.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        pieChartAttendance.setData(piedata);
```

> Xml code

```
  <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/pieChartAttendance"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
       />
```

Comment: so here,your table name is present and absent correct? actually am also having two tables like income and expense but i want the exact information in that pie-chart like you know for example rent xxx,salary xxx and you mentioned two slices but i want n slices because  it's depends upon the user.can you help me.if yes i owe you a beer  ;)

Comment: arrayList.add(new Entry(presentPercentage, 0));
arrayList.add(new Entry(absentPercentage, 1));
arrayList.add(new Entry(xxx_percentage, 2));
arrayList.add(new Entry(yyy_percentage, 3))

 arrayListXAxis.add("xxx");
arrayListXAxis.add("yyy");

colors.add(color for xxx);
colors.add(color for yyy);



;